# get a list of all erc20 tokens including address and decimals

Tags: solidity, web3js, nodejs

Is there a way to programmatically fetch a list of all erc20 tokens including contract addresses and decimals? Im using web3 but if there is any rest service I dont know Im happy to get to know about it.

Comment: Could you please provide more details about what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think what I am trying to accomplish is literally my question. Get a list of all erc20 tokens (name, decimals and so on) best case from some sort of open api

Answer (score 3):

Currently, there is no way to easily list ERC-20 token contracts on Ethereum blockchain. This is because contracts do not report any event when they are created.

One way to identify ERC-20 tokens would be

1. Listen for `Transfer` event for any contract
2. For any unidenfitied contract address
3. a) Check the address of the contract if it has `name` and `symbol` and `decimals` accessor function
4. b) Assume the contract implements ERC-20 if this is the case

Comment: Yes thank you, that would be the approach I was going for but I was hoping I could save me from doing that. Especially as I only have 1.000.000 requests with my teams plan on infura and I need these already for gathering all transactions of my app.

Comment: Host your own node. It it cheaper plus it is *much* faster. https://twitter.com/moo9000/status/1370323189486784513

Comment: Even with Infura or an own node which would require me a month to sync, I still dont know any way of getting what I need tho.

Comment: My tweet literally says it took less than 24h to sync, that's why I linked it. You are now pulling facts out from some Bitcoin maxi misinformation forum.

Comment: last time I ran a full node on a vps it took more than 3 weeks to have it completly synced. I cant imagine that you can load the whole eth chain in a few minutes. If that is true, it would be an option but I doubt it is.

Comment: Geth has since made a lot of improvements in its sync code. If you have fast enough internet and fast enough disk it should not take more than a day. Maybe your VPS is not powerful enough.

Comment: For the same price you pay for Infura, you can get a fast real hardware server from Hetzner.

Comment: I was able to sync a full ETH node in under 24 hours.  There are two key concerns: 1) must have enough disk space 2) must have fast disks (e.g. SSD)